# how to scan table for special characters

Tags: oracle, plsql

i am finding special characters by using dynamic sql and it is giving error. how to solve this error with this code

```
declare 
    type e_list is record (v_col varchar2(100),
                           v_num number);
                           r_rec e_list;
    type t_list_rec  is record
                              (table_name all_tab_columns.table_name%type,
                              column_name all_tab_columns.COLUMN_NAME%type);
    type t_list is table of t_list_rec index by PLS_INTEGER;
    v_array t_list;
    begin
    select /*+ parallel(14) */ table_name,column_name bulk collect into v_array from all_tab_columns where table_name=upper('fms_user_address_book') and OWNER='FMS_ADMIN';
    for i in 1..v_array.count() loop
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
          'select '||v_array(i).column_name||',count(*)  from '||v_array(i).table_name||' where not regexp_like ('||v_array(i).column_name||',''[A-za-z0-9.]'')
    group by '||v_array(i).column_name||''
          into r_rec;
          if r_rec.v_num<>0 then
        dbms_output.put_line(v_array(i).table_name||' -- '||v_array(i).column_name||'------------>>>>'||r_rec.v_col||' '||r_rec.v_num);
    end if;
    end loop;
    end;
```

Error

```
    ORA-01403: no data found
    ORA-06512: at line 13
    01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
    *Cause:    No data was found from the objects.
    *Action:   There was no data from the objects which may be due to end of fetch.
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to handle that exception by including additional (inner) `begin-exception-end` block within the loop.

Also, when working with dynamic SQL, it is usually a good idea to first compose statement you'll execute, display it, and - if everything is OK - run it. Then comment *displaying*:

Sample data: both `NAME` values are *wrong*, as well as one `ADDRESS`:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

        ID NAME   ADDRESS
---------- ------ ------------
         1 ab#def Test.address
         2 xy=z   w!(zf
```

Code; simplified version (without collections):

```
DECLARE
   l_cnt  NUMBER;
   l_str  VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
   FOR cur_r IN (SELECT table_name, column_name
                   FROM all_tab_columns
                  WHERE     table_name = UPPER ('test')
                        AND OWNER = 'SCOTT')
   LOOP
      BEGIN
         l_str :=
               'select count(*) from '
            || cur_r.table_name
            || ' where  regexp_like ('
            || cur_r.column_name
            || ',''[^a-zA-Z0-9.]'')';

         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str
            INTO l_cnt;
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
         THEN
            NULL;
      END;

      -- ... and ends here

      IF l_cnt > 0
      THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
               cur_r.table_name
            || ' -- '
            || cur_r.column_name
            || '------------>>>>'
            || l_cnt);
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Result:

```
TEST -- NAME------------>>>>2
TEST -- ADDRESS------------>>>>1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Getting below error by using your code ----->>>    Error report -
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 43
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested

Comment: Right; that's because GROUP BY clause which caused more than a single row to be returned. I modified code so that it works and included some sample rows; have a look, please. (When testing, don't forget to modify table and owner name!)

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is wrong as:

```sql
not regexp_like (column_name,'[A-za-z0-9.]')
```

Will find when there is one character that is in the range `A-z`, `a-z`, `0-9` or `.` and return `TRUE` if there is one such character and `FALSE` if there are no matching characters and then negate the boolean value. Effectively, you are looking for when the column contains no non-special characters and are not looking for at-least-one special character; so `'abc%def'` would not be matched as it contains a non-special character, even though it also contains a special character.

If you want to match special characters then use:

```sql
regexp_like (column_name,'[^A-Za-z0-9.]')
```

---

Regarding your code, you appear to want to count the instances of different pieces of data that contain special characters and can use:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sql   VARCHAR2(4000);
  v_value VARCHAR2(4000);
  v_cnt   PLS_INTEGER;
  v_cur   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN  
  FOR r IN (
    select owner,
           table_name,
           column_name
    from   all_tab_columns
    where  table_name=upper('fms_user_address_book')
    and    OWNER = 'FMS_ADMIN'
  ) loop
    v_sql := 'select "'||r.column_name||'" AS data,
              count(*) AS cnt
              from   "'||r.owner||'"."'||r.table_name||'"
              where  regexp_like ("'||r.column_name||'",''[^A-Za-z0-9.]'')
              group by "'||r.column_name||'"';
    -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);

    OPEN v_cur FOR v_sql;
    LOOP
      FETCH v_cur INTO v_value, v_cnt;
      EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
        r.owner || '.' || r.table_name || '.' || r.column_name  || '->' || v_value ||' ' || v_cnt
       );
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE FMS_ADMIN.FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK (a, b, c, "d", e) AS
SELECT 'a1', '$', 'c1', '-', '?' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a2', '$', 'c2', '^', '"&' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> FMS_ADMIN.FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK.B->$ 2
> FMS_ADMIN.FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK.d->- 1
> FMS_ADMIN.FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK.d->^ 1
> FMS_ADMIN.FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK.E->? 1
> FMS_ADMIN.FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK.E->"& 1
> ```

If you just want to count the number of rows containing special characters for each column then:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_sql   VARCHAR2(4000);
  v_cnt   PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN  
  FOR r IN (
    select owner,
           table_name,
           column_name
    from   all_tab_columns
    where  table_name=upper('fms_user_address_book')
    and    OWNER = 'FMS_ADMIN'
  ) loop
    v_sql := 'select count(*)
              from   "'||r.owner||'"."'||r.table_name||'"
              where  regexp_like ("'||r.column_name||'",''[^A-Za-z0-9.]'')';
    -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_cnt;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.owner || '.' || r.table_name || '.' || r.column_name  || '->' || v_cnt);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> FMS_ADMIN.FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK.A->0
> FMS_ADMIN.FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK.B->2
> FMS_ADMIN.FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK.C->0
> FMS_ADMIN.FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK.d->2
> FMS_ADMIN.FMS_USER_ADDRESS_BOOK.E->2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wwdCN_h_)

Comment: actually, i want the data like this query --->>select ADDRESS_1,count(*)  from fms_user_address_book where not regexp_like (ADDRESS_1,'[A-za-z0-9.]')
group by ADDRESS_1;  aboove code is showing count wuth column name but i want count with special character data like @ has count 5 and - has count 10